# OpenText Content Server and Import/Export/Manage

Tags: opentext

Is there any way to import/export/manage metadata using a spreadsheet using OpenText Content Server other than using a 3rd party company?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see (without a third party company module) is to implement your own module. This mean that you should have a good knowledge of Oscript and Java (in order to work with the spreadsheet document).

There is no out of the box feautere in CS.